# Web api 2 JSON output with named object

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-web-api2

I have an ApiController, with the following action:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage SearchPersons(string data)
{
    if (!_isAuthenticated) { return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized); }

    var results = new List<PersonSearchResult>();
    results.Add(new PersonSearchResult() { Name = "Mr. test", Sex = "male", Married = false });
    results.Add(new PersonSearchResult() { Name = "Mrs. test", Sex = "female", Married = true });
    results.Add(new PersonSearchResult() { Name = "Dr. test", Sex = "female", Married = false });

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, results, Request.GetConfiguration());
}
```

If authorized, it returns a list of PeopleSearchResults, and it looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Mr. test",
    "sex": "male",
    "married": false
  },
  {
    "name": "Mrs. test",
    "sex": "female",
    "married": true
  },
  {
    "name": "Dr. test",
    "sex": "female",
    "married": false
  }
]
```

But I want it to look more like this:

```
{
    "results": [{
        "name": "Mr. test",
        "sex": "male",
        "married": false
    }, {
        "name": "Mrs. test",
        "sex": "female",
        "married": true
    }, {
        "name": "Dr. test",
        "sex": "female",
        "married": false
    }]
}
```

Can I achieve this?

If not, how can I loop the first result using jQuery?
For now I tried like this, but IntelliSense tells me I can't loop it, no .Count is available on "data".
So I figure the nicest solution would be to wrap it like shown in the example I want, so I can loop data.results which should then have a .Count.

```
// search button action assignment:
$("#search-button").click(function () {
    var search = $("#search-input").val();
    if (search.trim() != "") {
        var ajax = $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/api/search/SearchPersons/" + search
        });

        ajax.done(function (data) {
            console.log("Done!");
            console.log(data);
        });

        ajax.fail(function (data) {
            console.log("Fail!");
            console.log(data);
        });

    } else {
        console.log("Empty search input value.");
        $("#search-input").focus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I achieve this?

Of course that you can. Start by writing a view model to reflect the required structure:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<PersonSearchResult> Results { get; set; }
}
```

and then return this view model instead of the original list:

```
var model = new MyViewModel();
model.Results = results;

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, model, Request.GetConfiguration());
```

> If not, how can I loop the first result using jQuery? For now I tried
>   like this, but IntelliSense tells me I can't loop it, no .Count is
>   available on "data".

`.Count` is a .NET property on the `ICollection<T>` class. In a javascript array, the corresponding property that you are looking for is called `.length`. So just make sure that if you want to loop over the returned collection in javascript, you are using the correct javascript property:

```
ajax.done(function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var item = data[i];
        console.log(item.name);
        console.log(item.sex);
        console.log(item.married);
    }
});
```

> So I figure the nicest solution would be to wrap it like shown in the
>   example I want, so I can loop data.results which should then have a
>   .Count.

Oh, no, `data.results` will be exactly the same array as if you haven't wrapped it in a view model. You still would have need to use the correct javascript property in order to loop over it:

```
ajax.done(function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
        var item = data.results[i];
        console.log(item.name);
        console.log(item.sex);
        console.log(item.married);
    }
});
```

Here's a [`good overview`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of how arrays work in javascript that I would recommend you reading through.

Comment: Very nice, I was hoping it would be this simple. I just tried a lot of different approaches, and in the end I guess I just confused myself a bit. I have tested the ViewModel approach, and it does exactly what I was hoping for :-) And sorry about the `.Count` references, I did mean `.length` I was just thinking .Net a bit too much when I wrote the question :-)
IntelliSense still doesn't think there is a `.length` even if the output is wrapped, but I guess that's because it is separated from the WebApi code, so it doesn't know what kind of object `data` is.